# How to use charting libraries in windows form application for compact windows?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce, visual-studio-2008-sp1, windows-embedded-compact

I want to develop windows form application for compact windows using C++ and I want use graphic libraries in that form. Is that possible.

I am using visual studio 2008 professional version. I am unable to even create a windows form application using C++ in that visual studio 2008 (previously I worked with visual studio 2022).